# How to perform conditional concatenation of strings in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Let's say I have three fields

```
{
    "Name": "Ben",
    "City": "London",
    "Country": "United Kingdom"
}
```

Now, when any one of these fields are empty, I don't want it to be concatenated in the final response.

Example:
if all three fields are populated, final result: `"Ben AND London AND United Kingdom"`,
if there are only two (let's say City and Country): `"London AND United Kingdom"`,
if there is only one: `"Ben"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either ways shown below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> (value)) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> accumulator ++ " AND " ++ item)
```

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> (value)) joinBy  " AND "
```

Answer (score 6):

Try filtering out empty values from the payload first and use joinBy to concatenate the strings:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var payload = { "Name": "Ben", "City": "London", "Country": "United Kingdom" }
---
(valuesOf(payload) filter !isBlank($)) joinBy " AND "
```

Comment: The import is unneeded

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

Input1:

```
{
    "Name": "Ben",
    "City": "London",
    "Country": "United Kingdom"
}
```

Dataweave script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var fields = [payload.Name, payload.City, payload.Country]
---
if (sizeOf(fields filter ($ != "")) > 1)
  joinBy(fields filter ($ != ""), " AND ")
else fields filter ($ != "")[0]
```

Output:

"Ben AND London AND United Kingdom"